# Install-WindowsFeature -ConfigurationFilePath from UNC path is denied

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a role template here (XML file) that I created to set up many IIS Servers at once. The template is on a UNC share that has Read access to the same user account that I am running remote powershell as. This account I am also using to RDP to these servers. If I run `Install-WindowsFeature -ConfigurationFilePath \\path\to\RoleTemplate.xml` on any server, it works just fine. But running that in the script block from one of the server to many others fails with 'Access to the path is denied'.

Is this running this command not supported from within a ScriptBlock?

---

Script example

```
$servers = "abc123 abc456 abc789";

ForEach ($server in ([regex]::matches($servers, "abc\d+") | %{$_.value})){
   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ArgumentList {param($server)} -ScriptBlock {

        # IIS Role Setup
        Install-WindowsFeature -ConfigurationFilePath \\path\to\RoleTemplate.xml

        # Other irrelevant commands...

   }
}
```

If I just run the command on its own on that server, using the same credentials, it works. However, running the same statement remotely gives up:

```
Access to the path '\\path\to\RoleTemplate.xml' is denied.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (\\path\to\...oleTemplate.xml:String) [Install-WindowsFeature], CmdletInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Install_WindowsFeature_ConfigurationFile_Import_Exception,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsFeatureCommand
    + PSComputerName        : abc123
```

Comment: It’s probably running in a different security context. This context evidently doesn’t have access to the share.

Comment: What is this security context? I am new to PS and just trying to piece things together. How do I set it or test to see what it is?

Comment: Just to clarify: the ScriptBlock runs in the security context of the user that has permission to access that share.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional investigation I've decided to use a workaround.

The workaround is to load role configuration xml into a variable, and then pass that variable to the `Invoke-Command` context, write the variable to a temporary file and then execute `Install-WindowsFeature` on that file. Not ideal, but it got the job done.

```
$roleconfig = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("\\path\to\RoleTemplate.xml")

ForEach ($server in ([regex]::matches($servers, "abc\d+") | %{$_.value})){
   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ArgumentList $roleconfig -EnableNetworkAccess -ScriptBlock {
        param($roleconfig)


        # IIS Role Setup
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\RoleTemplate.xml", $roleconfig)

        Install-WindowsFeature -ConfigurationFilePath C:\RoleTemplate.xml

        # Etc...
 }

}
```